# Java HTTP GET for bearer token?

Tags: java, http, authentication, get

I'd like to get a bearer token with Java. My API reference says to do a GET with curl:

```
curl -G "https://api.company.com/api/auth" --data-urlencode "username=<username>" --
data-urlencode "secret=<secret>"
```

Then, extract the “Value” property or the bearer token from the returned JSON object.

What is the equivalent way to do this with java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like this:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://api.company.com/api/auth?username=<username>&secret=<secret>");
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            int status = con.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            con.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Response status: " + status);
            System.out.println(content.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String params = "username=<username>&secret=<secret>";

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.company.com/api/auth?" + params);
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(request);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        try {
            System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```